# Is the phrase "Al Qaeda" a made up term?

Tags: cia, osama-bin-laden

Is the term "Al Qaeda" made up by the CIA or the FBI? (Tweet of a colleague, citing Adam Curtis' documentary "The Power of Nightmares")

> Even OBL hadn't heard the name "Al Qaeda" until the FBI/CIA decided it needed a name.

Alternatively, I've heard that it really means [The Database](http://www.globalresearch.ca/index.php?context=va&aid=24738)

> Shortly before his untimely death,
>   former British Foreign Secretary Robin
>   Cook told the House of Commons that
>   "Al Qaeda" is not really a terrorist
>   group but a database of international
>   mujaheddin and arms smugglers used by
>   the CIA and Saudis to funnel
>   guerrillas, arms, and money into
>   Soviet-occupied Afghanistan. Courtesy
>   of World Affairs, a journal based in
>   New Delhi, WMR can bring you an
>   important excerpt from an Apr.-Jun.
>   2004 article by Pierre-Henry Bunel, a
>   former agent for French military
>   intelligence.

Comment: Wikipedia's article on Al Qaeda cites CNN of an Al Jazeera interview with OBL where he claims how the term came about. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Qaeda#Etymology Whether you find trustworthy all of Wikipedia, CNN, Al Jazeera and bin Laden might be a stretch though.

Comment: My unsubstantiated knowledge is that USA thought it meant "The Database" due to a bad translation which is why they picked it to describe thier database of muslim terrorists who were not affiliated.

Comment: I read that the name was made up by Jamal al-Fadl in his testimony. The story goes that the government needed Bin Laden to be the head of a criminal organization to try him in absentia. al-Fadl supposedly made up the name Al-Qaeda as part of his deal since that's what the authorities wanted to hear.

Comment: AQ of course never was a single organisation, but rather seems to be a cooperative of other, smaller, organisations working towards a shared goal and having good use of a central planning and organisation committee (OBL and his cronies) as well as funding.

Comment: The name given to any human agency/organisation is obviously a made up term. Since the Americans were heavily involved with islamic terrorist outfits(or "resistance groups") during the Soviet invasion of Afghanistan, I don't really think it's noteworthy that the name was supplied by the americans.

Comment: Al Qaeda القاعدة actually means "the basis".

Answer (score 6):

I've never heard any claim that it was made up by CIA or FBI. Bin Ladin himself claimed the term was originally for "[training camps for our mujahedeen against Russia's terrorism](http://archives.cnn.com/2002/WORLD/asiapcf/south/02/05/binladen.transcript/index.html)" in a videotaped interview (Since I don't speak Arabic, I didn't seek out the original video tape, but trusted the English transcript), crediting Abu Ebeida El-Banashiri with the naming. I've always heard the translation being "the base," not "the database," which doesn't make much sense to me.

There's even an assertion that the name was [adapted from Isaac Asimov's "The Foundation"](http://www.guardian.co.uk/books/2002/aug/24/alqaida.sciencefictionfantasyandhorror). That seems a bit far fetched to me, but I suppose it's possible. I think it's more likely a coincidence, and the explanation given by bin Laden makes a lot more sense to me (being the simpler explanation, and seeing as it explains the name growing naturally from the movement before it formed into an organization).

Comment: “which doesn't make much sense to me” – read the post linked in the question: it actually makes a lot of sense to be using “base” as an abbreviation of “database”.

Comment: I mean that given the context the term is used in, having it come from a database doesn't make much sense to me. These guys aren't likely to be lead by DBAs, not are they likely to embrace a name given to them by the west, so the claim that the name comes from a name given to them by British and American intelligence agencies doesn't seem plausible to me. That's merely my opinion, though.

Comment: +1, but an answer citing something specifically addressing the "made up name" claim would be ideal.

Comment: The name wasn't taken from Asimov but the word Foundation in his series (surprisingly popular in the Arab world) was definitely translated as 'al Qaeda'. Maybe they use a different translation in newer editions?